# Security review vs lightning readiness

Tags: security-review

We're in the process of submitting the ap through Salesforce Security Review and kind of unsure if Lightning Readiness Report is important to pass the review.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Lightning Readiness was introduced as a "guideline" for new apps, then eventually became required for new apps (giving old apps time to catch up). I believe at this point, it's is absolutely imperative you be Lightning Ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightning Readiness is a requirement. All new apps entering Security Review, the final step before publishing on the AppExchange, must be Lightning Ready as a prerequisite.

For more info please look into below link
[Lightning Ready for AppExchange Partners (ISV)](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Lightning_Ready)